# Super a variable which contains a class?

Tags: python, class, oop, inheritance

Maybe there is a better way all together to do this, but overall, I have a generic class, which upon instantiating, I want to super another class (depending on what the input is). Almost create a 'router' in the Generic class init.

```
class GenericClass():
    def __init__(self, class_input, var):
        classes = {
            '1': Class1,
            '2': Class2
        }

        return_class = classes.get(class_input)

        # this is the part I can't figure out how to implement
        super().return_class().__init__(var)


class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, var):
        self.var=var

    def method1(self):
        raise NotImplementedError('sub-class should implement this.')

class Class1(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, var):
        super().__init__(var)

    def method1(self):
        print(self.var)


class Class2(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, var):
        super().__init__(var)

    def method1(self):
        print(self.var)
```

Maybe I'm just looking at this the wrong way. Open to methodology changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `GenericClass` is never actually used as a class, it shouldn't even be one - just make it a regular function, that creates and returns an instance of the specified class.  `super()` plays no part in this - the code would basically be `return classes[class_input](var)`.

If it did actually need to be a class (it's used as the base class of the classes you actually want to return, for example), you'd need to override `__new__()` instead (with exactly the same code as described above) - `__init__()` is too late to affect the class that is created.

Comment: Got it. I now understand `__new__` ! Thank you! Also thanks to @madjaoue for getting the ball rolling